# What I do to one button happens to the other

Tags: html, css, image, button, duplicates

I have some buttons for my enjin website, they are all supposed to go transparent when they are hovered over and they do, however the image on one button changes te image on the other.
For example:
Button 1 has a shield.
I will then make button 2 have a sword.
When I look back at button 1 that will also have a sword instead of a shield. 
I am not very experienced with coding so help would be very much appreciated. -Thank You.
Here is the code I use for it :

```
<a href="http://www.theuffclan.enjin.com/page404">
<!DOCTYPE html> <html > 
<head> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.pic { 
width:312px; 
height:250px; 
opacity: 1; 
filter: alpha(opacity=100); 
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/qLQkmOC.png) no-repeat; 
} 
.pic:hover { 
opacity: 0.3; 
filter: alpha(opacity=30); 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div class="pic"> </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: please format your code for better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use class "pic".
Which will give all buttons with that class the same behavior. Try using id

Div id = "pic"

Css

## pic {your css}

Different ids for each pic

It helps if your code has buttons in it

Hashtag before pic not showing in anwser

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events .

```
    function onHover()
{
    $("#menuImg2").attr('src', 'imageURL_OnMouseOver');
}

function offHover()
{
    $("#menuImg2").attr('src', 'imageURL_OnMouseOut');
}


<img id='menuImg' src="defaultImageURL" alt="logo" width="300px" height="150px"  

onmouseover="onHover();" onmouseout="offHover();" />
```

You can check my fiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5JGRJ/330/) !

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use jquery for replacing the background images on hover. you can do it by insert the hovered element's background image into a var and adding it to all the others target elements with inline style, after mouse leave removing the style attr.

HTML:

```
<div class="pic shield"></div>
<div class="pic sword"></div>
<div class="pic horse"></div>
<div class="pic castle"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.pic 
{ 
    width:50%; 
    height:250px;
    opacity: 1; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
} 

.pic:hover 
{ 
    opacity: 0.3; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=30); 
} 

.shield
{
    background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/64272.png); 
}

.sword
{
    background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/31702.png); 
}

.horse
{
    background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/32403.png); 
}

.castle
{
    background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/1010.png); 
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.pic').hover(function(){
        var ThisImage = $(this).css('background');
        $('.pic').css('background', ThisImage);
    },function(){
        $('.pic').removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qo4Lnemq/2/